# How do I stop XCode from downloading and installing iOS and OSX libraries?

Tags: macos, xcode4.3, updates

I've been developing small apps for iOS on my Macbook Air for a couple of months now. It's actually reasonably fast.

Mac OS X 10.7.3
1.6 GHz Intel Core Duo
2 GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM
80 GB ATA Disk
XCode 4.3.2

Today it all ground to a halt. XCode says it downloads and installs iOS 5.1 and OS X 10.7.

XCode is the only application I'm running, so I think the download and install is the problem.

I've lost a days work for no reason. I don't want to lose any more.

How do I prevent XCode from doing downloading and installing unwanted features again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Uncheck "Check for and install updates automatically
```

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to _only_ do this for xcode? I want the updates for other apps.

Comment: just like automatic update stop not running download apps stop so please idea about  stop running download....